# Why is it best if we light ghee lamp in the house while praying?

Tags: belief, worship, prayer

Before starting any prayer it is required that we light a lamp which is made up of oil and cotton wick. But it is considered *uttam* (best) if ghee (Clarified butter) is used instead of oil. Why is ghee considered *uttam*?

Comment: I was thinking to write one over this but in a different way, anyways you posted, nice one..

Comment: I would like to point out that your question speaks different and your description speaks different, I will answer according to the question title, but please clear the doubt by edit if you can

Comment: I have heard that if you light a desi ghee and saffron diya the illness goes away ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you pointed 'ghee' is considered as the best for lighting lamps in houses and also in temples. This is the product extracted from milk of cows, which is considered sacred. Ghee is one of the purest form of milk which is extracted from the butter. As we all know cow milk has  some medicinal qualities. Since ghee is the purest form of milk, it will have it's highest qualities. When we use ghee lamp it helps to purify the atmosphere.

The following information is taken from [this reference](http://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/why-is-ghee-lamp-preferred-to-oil-lamp-during-puja-ritual.html)

> "Agni Puran clearly states that only oil or Ghee (clarified butter) be
>   used in the lamp meant for puja and no other combustible substance.
>   According to the Science of spirituality the lamp with clarified
>   butter is more sattvik (spiritually pure) as compared to lamp in which
>   oil is used.
>
> Generally the use of oil is more prevalent than that of Ghee. The oil
>   containing lamp kindles longer while the ghee containing lamp kindles
>   for a short period.
>
> - Ghee lamp has more capacity to attract the sattvik vibrations present in the surrounding atmosphere as compared to oil lamp.
> - The oil lamp can attract the sattvik vibrations spread over a maximum distance of 1 meter while the ghee lamp can attract sattvik
>     vibrations spread over till Swarga Lok (heaven)
> - When the oil lamp stops burning the predominance of raja particles in the atmosphere is enhanced and lasts for half an hour. On the other
>     hand when the ghee lamp stops burning the impact of sattvikta (the
>     quality of being sattvik) on the atmosphere is experienced even after
>     four hours.
>
> **Effect on the worshipper as per Kundalini Yog**
>
> According to yogic path of Kundalini Yog there are seven principle
>   chakras or energy centers in the human being. These chakras influence
>   practically every aspect of human being including physical body, mind
>   and intellect. The oil lamp is effective in purification of Muladhar
>   and Swadhishthan Chakra only to certain extent but the ghee lamp
>   purifies Manipur and  Anahat chakras to a significant  extent. Just as
>   there are seven chakras in the human body, there are paths for the
>   flow of vital energy (chetana). These are called as Nadis or channels.
>   The three principle nadis are Chandra nadi (Moon channel), Surya nadi
>   (Sun channel) and Sushumna nadi. When Chandra nadi is active the
>   person perceives coolness. The activation of Surya nadi imparts energy
>   to the person. The Sushumna nadi is activated when the person starts
>   progressing spiritually. The oil lamp activates the Surya nadi of the
>   person while ghee lamp activates only that nadi which is essential to
>   the worshipper in a particular action.
>
> **Effect on the subtle sheaths of the worshipper**
>
> According to the science of spirituality the body which is visible to
>   our eyes is called Annamaya Kosha or food sheath. Besides this there
>   are four other Koshas namely Pranmaya Kosha or vital air sheath,
>   Manomaya Kosha or the mental sheath, Vidnyanmaya Kosha or sheath of
>   intellect and Anandmaya Kosha or bliss sheath. The Pranmaya kosha  is
>   a seat for the Pancha pranas (five vital air elements) which provides
>   energy to the gross body. The second Manomaya kosha is the seat of
>   emotions. The third Vidnyanmaya Kosha is the seat of intellect and the
>   fourth Anandamaya Kosha is the seat of Soul which is of the nature of
>   existence, consciousness and bliss (satchidananda). Even these subtle
>   sheaths or koshas are affected by the oil or ghee lamps. The oil lamp
>   imparts power to the raja particles in the Pranamaya kosha which makes
>   the individual restless. The ghee lamp strengthens the sattva
>   particles of Pranamaya kosha and Manomaya Kosha and as a result of
>   this the jiva (individual, embodied soul) becomes peaceful,stable and
>   happy.
>
> **Spiritual experience imparted by oil and ghee lamps**
>
> When we see subtle light or vision of a deity then it is an example of
>   spiritual experience related to Tej tattva or absolute fire element.
>   When we experience a feeling of touch without any external reason 
>   then it is a spiritual experience related to Vayu tattva or absolute
>   air element. The ghee lamp gives spiritual experience of Tej tatva and
>   Vayu tattva to the worshipper."

Comment: Absolutely content by your answer. I am glad I am not in the wrong place, of which I had been skeptical.

Comment: wow, late to see this. Mr.Alien's answer and this answer has the same [reference](http://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/why-is-ghee-lamp-preferred-to-oil-lamp-during-puja-ritual.html). But looks like he read only first part. Actually this answer("OFF-TOPIC SCIENCE ANSWER")  is from the same article...Has anybody clicked the link for references in both answers?

Answer (score 11):

Lamps / Diya we say have special meaning in Hindu dharma.

Lightness is a symbol of *knowledge* which in a way removes ignorance amongst humans, just as light removes darkness.

Since old days, people lit lamps around their homes, in temples etc just to ignore darkness because some people relate darkness with evil spirits, bad demons etc.

Some ignore doing *(shubh)* [Good] *(karya)* [work] in darkness, and hence they do it in the early morning (when there's light[prakash])

I would like to share a snippet from Sanskrit

> असतोमा सद्गमय। 
>   **तमसोमा ज्योतिर् गमया।**
>   मृत्योर्मामृतं गमय॥ ॐ शांति
>   शांति शांति - बृहदारण्यक उपनिषद् 1.3.28.

Here, the sentence I have highlighted is pronounced as *"Tamso maa jyotir gamaya"* which means *From darkness, lead me to light*.

---

Now why do we use Ghee and why not candles? Ghee which is made out of cows milk is preferred or in your words, its considered as uttam as it spreads vibrations which helps human talk with Gods and Godesses.

There is a difference between lighting a lamp with ghee, oil and candles, I already explained you about the ghee, but when one lits the lamp with oil, it spreads the vibration which helps you talk with your ancestors.

And the one which lits up with candles spreads vibrations which helps one communicate with Evil spirits(Demons). Hence when you see, some people do black magic tricks to interact with the souls (Aatma) they use candles while doing so.

---

Also, as far as I remember, recently I visited Tirupati mandir, where they still don't use artificial lights in the inner main room where they've kept lord Tirupati's murthi, they use diya instead which is nothing but a natural form of light.

To support my answer, I would like to link to a [similar article](http://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/why-is-ghee-lamp-preferred-to-oil-lamp-during-puja-ritual.html) which has similar views over this and is covered in detail

Comment: I have realised that when we lit a lamp of oil it makes the room black because of the charcoal it forms. But the Ghee lamp does not do so, rather makes the ambience very serene. Is this what you mean by talk with Gods..

Comment: @pritywiz No, its when you are doing puja of the idol, it generates positive vibrations around, just as we play drums and other instruments in our mandirs during aarti, it spreads positivity, same way, using ghee helps your feelings/prayers connect with god in a better way

Comment: I would like more scientific reason for the same. All that is said here is mainly about beliefs. But in the modern world people would like to know how these are connected scientifically. Talking to God -- by lighting a ghee deepak does not really convince ones who do not believe in these system. Looking for scientific reasons.

Comment: @pritywiz Sorry, than you are at a wrong place, [we don't provide scientific reasons here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/121/political-questions-and-scientific-questions-will-be-considered-off-topic), you can ask the same question on Physics, Chemistry or Biology whichever you may is fit for your question

Comment: All practices and beliefs in Hinduism is scientific. It is part of this religion, I am surprised by this answer.

Comment: @pritywiz Yes but we don't provide science behind religion here, you will get religious answers only

Comment: i would like to make point regarding tirupathi mandir that in south india almost all the temples are using lamps in place of artificial light.

Comment: Several other posts have scientific clarification to their answer. Looking for better justification to the answer.

Comment: @pritywiz Please raise a post on meta if you want scientific answers, also, share the link where you saw scientific answers

Comment: @pritywiz you are right there is a scientific reasoning and it is there in the answer selected by you. As runningmind said it creates sattvic vibration, because ghee's particles are not all burnt and they enter our body also through air. you wll find benefits of ghee http://healthmeup.com/news-healthy-living/health-benefits-of-pure-ghee/17397